# Multivariate Ornstein–Uhlenbeck process, examples with complex eigenvalues

Tags: multivariate-analysis, references, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus

We know that mathematically the drift matrix of the multivariate OU process can have real or complex eigenvalues. In case of real eigenvalues, the process is called non-oscillating whereas in case of complex eigenvalues, the process is called oscillating.

This [article](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.2044-8317.2012.02043.x) well explain the difference between oscillating and non-oscillating processes but it uses simulated examples. I am trying to look for real examples so that they can clarify the difference between the cases of real and complex eigenvalues.

Do you see any articles where the authors assume oscillating OU process for a real analysis?

Comment: This may be obvious, but my experience with complex eigenvalues stems from the determination of the algebraic roots of a determinant equation. In the latter, complex eigenvalues equate to the complex roots of a polynomial equation.

Comment: @AJKOER: I have just edited the question. Do you see anywhere the authors assume oscillating OU process for a real analysis?